# Magento core_config_data table appears to be compromised

Tags: security, magento

A Magento website I am hosting has been hacked with the webpages starting to show ads and links for other websites at the top and bottom. I tracked this down to the core_config_data mysql table which has rows being added with the html for the adds. I have removed the ads but obvioulsy there is nothing to stop them reappearing. What is the best way of protecting this table from being accessed again? On WordPress there is an awesome security plugin called WordFence, is there anything similar for Magento?